# Why am I getting the "wrong type" error here?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have following two TypeScript classes:

```
export class AbsenceWithUser {
    @jsonProperty(Absence) public readonly absence: Absence;
    @jsonProperty(User) public readonly user: User;

    constructor(absence: Absence, user: User) {
        this.absence = absence;
        this.user = user;
    }
}

export class Birthday {
    @jsonProperty(MomentDateJson) public readonly birthday: moment.Moment;
    @jsonProperty(User) public readonly user: User;

    constructor(birthday: moment.Moment, user: User) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

I need to create an array, elements of which can be instances of either `AbsenceWithUser` or `Birthday`. I do this using the following method:

```
private getAllEvents():(AbsenceWithUser|Birthday)[] {
    const absences = this.props.absences as (AbsenceWithUser|Birthday)[];
    const birthdays = this.props.birthdays as (AbsenceWithUser|Birthday)[];
    return absences.concat(birthdays);
}
```

However, if I create an array using `getAllEvents`, its elements are not recognized as instances of either class. I have the following function:

```
private eventToDate(x:AbsenceWithUser | Birthday):Moment {
    if (x instanceof AbsenceWithUser) {
        return x.absence.endDate;
    } else if (x instanceof Birthday) {
        return x.birthday;
    } else {
        throw new Error("Unknown event type, x: " + x);
    }
}
```

The following code produces an Error "Unknown event type".

```
const events = this.getAllEvents();
this.eventToDate(events[0]);
```

How should I change my code so that I can distinguish between `AbsenceWithUser` and `Birthday` in `eventToDate`?

Note that it doesn't need to be `instanceof`.

**Update 1 (13:27 01.10.2017 MSK):**

Tried to change `getEvents` method to this:

```
private getAllEvents():(AbsenceWithUser|Birthday)[] {
    const absences:(AbsenceWithUser|Birthday) = this.props.absences as (AbsenceWithUser|Birthday)[];
    const birthdays:(AbsenceWithUser|Birthday) = this.props.birthdays as (AbsenceWithUser|Birthday)[];
    return absences.concat(birthdays);
}
```

Now I'm getting errors like `Error:(127, 15) TS2322:Type '(AbsenceWithUser | Birthday)[]' is not assignable to type 'AbsenceWithUser | Birthday'.
  Type '(AbsenceWithUser | Birthday)[]' is not assignable to type 'Birthday'.
    Property 'birthday' is missing in type '(AbsenceWithUser | Birthday)[]'.` in WebStorm.

**Update 2 (13:31 01.10.2017 MSK):** I tried to create an empty array and then use `concat` to merge absences and birthdays arrays into one. For this I create the following array:

```
const a:(AbsenceWithUser|Birthday) = [];
```

WebStorm reports this error: `Error:(127, 15) TS2322:Type 'never[]' is not assignable to type 'AbsenceWithUser | Birthday'. Type 'never[]' is not assignable to type 'Birthday'. Property 'birthday' is missing in type 'never[]'.`

I have no idea where `never[]` type comes from.

**Update 3 (13:46 01.10.2017 MSK):** Fixed obvious type bugs in `getAllEvents`.

```
private getAllEvents():(AbsenceWithUser|Birthday)[] {
    const absences:(AbsenceWithUser|Birthday)[] = this.props.absences as (AbsenceWithUser|Birthday)[];
    const birthdays:(AbsenceWithUser|Birthday)[] = this.props.birthdays as (AbsenceWithUser|Birthday)[];
    const allEvents:(AbsenceWithUser|Birthday)[] = absences.concat(birthdays);
    return allEvents;
}
```

**Update 4 (14:01 01.10.2017 MSK):**

Another attempt:

```
export type EventTypes = (AbsenceWithUser|Birthday);

private isEmpty(arr:EventTypes[]):boolean {
    return arr.length === 0;
}

private getAllEvents():EventTypes[] {
    const absences:EventTypes[] = this.props.absences as EventTypes[];
    const birthdays:EventTypes[] = this.props.birthdays as EventTypes[];
    const absencesEmpty:boolean = this.isEmpty(absences);
    const birthdaysEmpty:boolean = this.isEmpty(birthdays)
    if (absencesEmpty && !birthdaysEmpty) {
        return birthdays;
    } else if (absencesEmpty && birthdaysEmpty) {
        return [];
    } else if (!absencesEmpty && !birthdaysEmpty) {
        return absences.concat(birthdays);
    } else if (!absencesEmpty && birthdaysEmpty) {
        return absences;
    }
    return [];
}
```

**Update 5 (15:28 01.10.2017 MSK):** Final version:

```
private getAllEvents():EventTypes[] {
    const absences:EventTypes[] = this.props.absences.map(absenceJson => {
        return new AbsenceWithUser(absenceJson.absence, absenceJson.user);
    });
    const birthdays:EventTypes[] = this.props.birthdays.map(birthdayJson => {
        return new Birthday(birthdayJson.birthday, birthdayJson.user);
    });
    const absencesEmpty = this.isEmpty(absences);
    const birthdaysEmpty = this.isEmpty(birthdays);
    if (absencesEmpty && birthdaysEmpty) {
        return [];
    } else if (absencesEmpty && !birthdaysEmpty) {
        return birthdays;
    } else if (!absencesEmpty && birthdaysEmpty) {
        return absences;
    } else {
        return absences.concat(birthdays);
    }
}
```

Note that you can theoretically use `Object.assign` in order to convert objects deserialized from JSON to Typescript class instances (if your environment supports it).

Comment: I'm very new to TS, but could you try typing the constants like: const absences(AbsenceWithUser|Birthday)[] = this.props.absences;  

In strict typed languages generally it is not possible to cast a whole set within a vector using "as" ...needs to be defined first... but I am still a TS newb so don't know how this actually parses differently (if it does at all)...

Comment: @joshstrike Thanks for your comment. I tried out what you proposed -- see update 1.

Comment: @joshstrike It is very strange -- even creatng an **empty** array with `(AbsenceWithUser|Birthday)` type doesn't work (see update 2).

Comment: But why are you casting at all? Is `this.props.absences` not the correct type? Please note that casting your props to `(AbsenceWithUser|Birthday)[]` will not automatically convert it to the right type.

Comment: @Kokodoko Because I'm new to Typescript and trying all ways to combine two arrays into one. If I am completely wrong, please tell me how I can create an array of type `A|B[]` from two arrays, one of which has the type `A[]` and the other `B[]`.

Comment: Where is the data coming from? Unless you are manually creating instances of your classes, as opposed to directly using deserialized data, `instanceof` will always be false.

Comment: @AluanHaddad You were right about the deserialized data. I modified the code so that I convert them into TypeScript class instances (see update 5). Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @DP_ sure thing. Note that I would argue that is a very bad direction to take. This complicates your serialization dependent code immensely. Instead, eschew classes and use interfaces for working with JSON. You will inevitably forget to instantiate the class somewhere or other, but you don't need a class at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created an example that shows how to merge two arrays of a specific type into an array that can have items of both types. You can use `instanceof` to check the type.

```
class AbsenceWithUser {
    public readonly when: string;
    public readonly user: string;
}

class Birthday {
    public readonly day: string;
    public readonly user: string;
}

class Test {

    constructor(){
      let absences : AbsenceWithUser[] = [new AbsenceWithUser(), new AbsenceWithUser()]
      let birthdays : Birthday[] = [new Birthday(), new Birthday(), new Birthday()]

      let combined:(AbsenceWithUser | Birthday)[] = this.mergeArrays(absences, birthdays)

      if (combined[0] instanceof Birthday) {
        console.log("we have a birthday")
      } else { 
        console.log("we have an absence")
      }

    }

    private mergeArrays(absences: AbsenceWithUser[], birthdays: Birthday[]): (AbsenceWithUser | Birthday)[] {
        var allEvents : (AbsenceWithUser | Birthday)[] = [...birthdays].concat(...absences);
        return allEvents;
    }
}
```